# How to add arrays into numpy matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

For example I want to put the first element from list "z" into a matrix from numpy as seen below

```
z = [1,2]
A = np.mat("12,z[0],-12,6;6,4,-6,2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular `array` constructor.

```
In [167]: z=[1,2]
In [168]: arr = np.array([[ 1,z[0], 2], [3, 4, z[1]]])
In [169]: arr
Out[169]: 
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 2]])
```

The `mat('1 2; 3 4')` form is supposed to help MATLAB users adjust to `numpy`. It isn't meant for complex entries. The string parser in this expression cannot handle variables and expressions.

`np.matrix` use is discouraged, because it adds complications in many cases.  It will remain in `numpy` for a long time, but unless you really need some special feature, don't use it.

---

That said, a new feature in the base Python string formatting makes this kind of expression easier:

```
In [171]: np.matrix(f'1,{z[0]},2;3,4,{z[1]}')
Out[171]: 
matrix([[1, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 2]])
```

The new `f''` string can handle variable and expression substitution:

```
In [172]: f'1,{z[0]},2;3,4,{z[1]}'
Out[172]: '1,1,2;3,4,2'
In [175]: np.matrix(f'1,{z[0]},2;3,4,{sum(z)}')
Out[175]: 
    matrix([[1, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check This:**

```
import numpy as np

z = [1, 2]
A = np.matrix('12, ' + str(z[0]) + ' , -12, 6 ; 6, 4, -6, 2')
print(A)

#returns/Output

[[ 12   1 -12   6]
 [  6   4  -6   2]]
```

Comment: `np.matrix` is going to be deprecated. Please avoid using it anymore.

Comment: Oki i will remember this :) Thankyou!